# Concurrency in Shell Scripts

Tags: shell

Use case: I have 5 docker images I want to build, and then I want to execute the push command. I would like the 5 images to build in parallel and when they are done, push to docker hub.

Similar to:

```
docker build -t "wblankenship/test:1" ./test1 &
docker build -t "wblankenship/test:2" ./test2 &
docker build -t "wblankenship/test:3" ./test3 &
docker build -t "wblankenship/test:4" ./test4 &
docker build -t "wblankenship/test:5" ./test5 &

// Wait here for the previous 5 commands to finish

docker push wblankenship/test
```

Is this possible?

Comment: While this thread contains useful information, I think it is important to note that Docker does not run concurrently. So even if you submit these build requests to the daemon in parallel, the will be run serially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was simple. I used gnu parallel.

Final product looks like:

```
parallel "docker build -t crackerz/nodejs:{} $DIR/dist/{} 2>&1 | tee ./logs/{}.log" ::: wheezy jessie sid precise saucy trusty

docker push crackerz/nodejs 2>&1 | tee ./logs/push.log
```

Comment: Since you are putting the output into files, consider using --results instead of tee

Answer (score 5):

Just use `wait`

```
process &
process &
process &
wait
```

With no parameters it waits for all background processes to finish. With a PID it waits for the specific process.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `xargs` can try the next:

```
seq 5 | xargs -P0 -i -n1 echo docker build -t "wblankenship/test:{}" ./test{} ; wait
```

The above if for "dry run", remove the `echo` when you satisfied for the normal execution.

the:

```
-P0 mean - run the commands as many times is possible in background
```

and the `wait` will ... ehm.. wait. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Something like:

```
parallel docker build -t "wblankenship/test:1" ./test1
parallel docker build -t "wblankenship/test:2" ./test2
parallel docker build -t "wblankenship/test:3" ./test3
parallel docker build -t "wblankenship/test:4" ./test4
parallel docker build -t "wblankenship/test:5" ./test5
```

Comment: No, you would want something like `echo {1..5} | parallel docker build -t ...{} ...{}`